# how to add even row number data into first column and odd row number data into the second column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a help to add even row number data into first column and odd row number data into the second column. Using SQL server 2008 / SQL server 2008 R2...

**Example**

```
id      Data
1       TK104
2       ABC   
3       TK106
4       XYZ
```

**LOOKING FOR OUTPUT LIKE**

```
NAME          VALUE
TK104         ABC
TK106         XYZ
```

Comment: No gaps, always even number of rows? Do a self join.

Answer (score 1):

If your `id` can contain 'gaps' use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation

```
select 
     max(case when rn % 2 = 0 then data end) as name,
     max(case when rn % 2 = 1 then data end) as value
from
(
  select *, 
         row_number() over (order by id) as rn 
  from your_table
)
group by rn / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you're referring to a temporary table, but if you mean this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ReturnData (Column1 VARCHAR(50), Column2 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #ReturnData (Column1, Column2) (
  SELECT
     CASE WHEN MyTable.ID % 2 = 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, whateverdata) ELSE '' END,
     CASE WHEN MyTable.ID % 2 > 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, whateverdata) ELSE '' END
  FROM MyTable
)


SELECT * FROM #ReturnData
DROP TABLE #ReturnData
```

This will give you even in first column, odd in second. An example from a table in one of our db's:

```
(106 rows affected)
Column1                                            Column2
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
652                                                
                                                   653
654                                                
                                                   655
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it looks like you want to join records where id = i with records where id = i+1. If so, you should self-join the table on that criteria:

```
SELECT A.Data NAME, B.Data VALUE 
FROM Example A FULL JOIN Example B -- Self-join. Using a FULL join in case of gaps
ON A.id + 1 = B.id
AND B.id % 2 = 1 --Make sure that Value is odd 
AND A.id % 2 = 0 --Name is even
```

Comment: `... AND B.id % 2 = 1` (To keep FULL OUTER JOIN.)

Comment: The issue @jarlh commented on has been fixed.